# ArcMap maintaining raster cell size when using math?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, resolution

I have a raster created from importing xy data (it has lat, lon, and a value field [WGS84]). The raster resolution is 60 meters as that's my required accuracy and for my value field I'd like to maintain around 6 decimal places.

I need to change this to integer in order to change the system to New Zealand Map Grid 1949 to align with my other data. However, when I use times in order to maintain my value field accuracy the cell size gets huge (10 km or so). The same occurs when I use int.

How do i maintain my 60 meter resolution to obtain my polygon for later transformation, to then change back to raster to continue with my work?

Comment: Have you set the Cell Size and Snap Raster environment settings? if so what are they set to?

Comment: If you're using a geographic coordinate system, then the raster resolution isn't really 60 meters, it's a rough approximation of 60 meters, varying by row.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I assume what you're referring to are the options in the environment settings? If so then I have tried altering raster analysis and XY resolution and tolerance. Altering these or trying to use another DEM as reference for it, I end up with errors saying table not found, no spatial reference exists, unable to set analysis window, error in executing grid. Perhaps I am going about this all wrong. From what I've found I can't do anything with a floating point raster but changing it to integer loses all my detail.

Comment: @Vince I realise this but a rough approximation of 60 meters when projected isnt 15 km.